# How automatic download works using blob URL's and programmatic click events?

Tags: javascript, dom, download

I recently needed to implement an automatic download of a CSV file in javascript. I didn't want to use any 3rd party libraries so instead I studies how the 3rd party libraries do it. I took a look at FileSaver npm package specifically at the function `saveAs` from [here](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js).

Eventually I changed the code to suit my needs into something like this:

```
class BlobDownload {
  constructor(window, blob, fileName, contentType) {
    this.window = window;
    this.document = window.document;
    this.blob = blob;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.contentType = contentType;
  }

  asyncCreateObjectURL = blob => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const blobURL = this.window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      blobURL ? resolve(blobURL) : reject();
    });
  }

  click = (node) => {
    try {
      node.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
    } catch (e) {
      const evt = this.document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
      evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, this.window, 0, 0, 0, 80,
        20, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
      node.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
  };

  download = async () => {
    const blob = new Blob([this.blob], { type: this.contentType });
    const a = this.document.createElement('a');
    a.download = this.fileName;
    a.href = await this.asyncCreateObjectURL(blob);
    setTimeout(() => { this.window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href) }, 60000) // 1min
    setTimeout(() => { this.click(a) }, 0)
  }
}

export default BlobDownload;
```

I don't understand a few things in the code though:

1. we're create an `a` node but it doesn't display anywhere on the page. Where does this node actually reside, only as an object in RAM?
2. the function `click` dispatched click event immediately, but if this doesn't work it creates a new event and then dispatches it. Why do we need to account for the case where simple dispatching doesn't work?
3. the whole procedure of creating an temporary `a` link and artificially clicking on it seems like a hack. Is this really a good pattern or better practices exist to download files?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. we're create an `a` node but it doesn't display anywhere on the page. Where does this node actually reside, only as an object in RAM?

Yes, it will only reside in the memory but it's still possible to call an event on it as evident by the source code. Note: this will not work on iOS Safari. There you have to display the actual link and prompt the user to tap it - there's a note about it on [FileSaver.js's README.md](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/README.md).

> 2. the function `click` dispatched click event immediately, but if this doesn't work it creates a new event and then dispatches it. Why do we need to account for the case where simple dispatching doesn't work?

Reading the MDN page for [`initMouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent) tells us it deprecated. If the click function fails and the try-catch is triggered then we're on a really old browser where `initMouseEvent` should be available. If you go back in the commit history the code used to be far more complicated due to edge cases and ultimately not needed feature detection.

> 3. the whole procedure of creating an temporary a link and artificially clicking on it seems like a hack. Is this really a good pattern or better practices exist to download files?

It's a hack, there's no way around it. Best practices won't get you far if you need to have backwards compatibility. FileSaver.js strives to abstract away all of the gnarly hacking needed to handle programmatic file saving so that you don't have to.

In general I would advise against copying over library code for a custom implementation. FileSaver.js is over 9 years old now and still relevant. Having it as a package.json dependency or a copy-paste in a library folder would preserve it's attribution making maintenance easier on the next guy :).

In general it's a good set of questions! I'm also implementing a CSV download feature right now. I stumbled on it from googling based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57824019) while trying to get file saving to work with Web Workers without the need to `postMessage` the contents of a file. Apparently passing only an URL to a blob is enough for `saveAs` to work!

```
// in web worker return from promise-worker/postMessage ->
URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' }));
// on main thread
saveAs(objectURLCreatedAbove);
// done :)
```

Consider using Web Workers if your CSV's get big and there are considerable freezes when you prepare data for downloading. The [sheetjs library](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs) is also quite helpful if you need to do anything with spreadsheet data.

Happy coding!